# Proto3 compiler did not generate a put method for Map fields

Tags: java, dictionary, protocol-buffers

I create message with map, and use proto3(protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3.1-windows-x86_64.exe compiler) to generate java pojo. But in message builder there is no put method for map.

Here is proto file fragment:

```html
message User {
 map<string, string> contacts = 1;
 int32 id = 2;
 string name = 3;
 int32 age = 4;
 string email = 5;
}
```

In User.Builder there is no putAllContacts() method.

In [google's document](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#map-fields) it's said

```html
The compiler will generate the following method only in the message's builder:

Map<Integer, Integer> getMutableWeight();: Returns a mutable Map. Note that multiple calls to this method may return different map instances. The returned map reference may be invalidated by any subsequent method calls to the Builder.
Builder putAllWeight(Map<Integer, Integer> value);: Adds all entries in the given map to this field.
```

Though I can use these code to put key/value into map

```
User.Builder builder = User.newBuilder();
Map<String,String> contacts = builder.getMutableContacts();
contacts.put("key", "value");
```

I still wonder why my generated java pojo has no put method for map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the newest version v3.0.0-beta-1? I remember this putXXX() method is only added recently. It's probably not in alpha-3.